# Android Reformat Date in View Binder

Tags: android

Here's what i'm trying to do, i've got a viewbinder and i want to reformat the date in here and set the text. I don't know what i'm doing wrong but i get a ton of warning and it just locks up. Here's the code:

```
  private class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

        if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE)) {
            String date = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getActivity());
            String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

             TextView tv = (TextView) view;
             tv.setText(formatedDate);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Warnings:

```
    06-13 10:19:07.453: W/System.err(21766): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:365)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at com.projectcaruso.naturalfamilyplaning.HistoryFragment$CustomViewBinder.setViewValue(HistoryFragment.java:101)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:146)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:250)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
    06-13 10:19:07.513: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.523: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.523: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    06-13 10:19:07.523: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    06-13 10:19:07.523: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    06-13 10:19:07.533: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.543: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.543: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    06-13 10:19:07.543: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.543: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.543: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
    06-13 10:19:07.553: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
    06-13 10:19:07.553: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
    06-13 10:19:07.553: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.553: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.553: W/System.err(21766):    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:476)
    06-13 10:19:07.563: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.563: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.563: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
    06-13 10:19:07.563: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.563: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4656)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1826)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1121)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    06-13 10:19:07.583: W/System.err(21766):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    06-13 10:19:07.593: W/System.err(21766):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-13 10:19:07.773: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21766): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
    06-13 10:19:07.773: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(21766): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

XML CLIP:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCreatedAt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:text="@string/defDate" />
```

CHANGED TO:

```
  private Date parseDate(String date) {
        SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateObj = new Date();

        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(date);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateObj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

         if (columnIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(StatusData.KEY_CHARTING_DATE)) {
             SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
             String date = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             Date dateObj = parseDate(date);

             String formatedDate = format.format(dateObj);

             TextView tv = (TextView) view;
             tv.setText(formatedDate);
             return true;
         }
```

Comment: Can you please post the errors from your logcat?

Comment: "but i get a ton of warning and it just locks up" - It would help if you showed us the warnings

Comment: Also, is that cursor being closed?

Comment: The cursor is still open at this point

Comment: Ok. Pretty sure you're passing in an invalid parameter in the `dateFormat.format()`. What value is being passed in there. What is it's format?

Comment: The string from the table is 2013-06-13

Comment: ok, looking at the return of the function my answer was wrong so i removed it. I agree with @Don . You should check what comes out of the cursor. and i cannot find an overload of the method `format` that receives a string

Comment: @jcaruso I've added an answer. Please let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in an illegal parameter to the `dateFormat.format()`. It should be a `Date` object. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) for other valid parameters.

Comment: ok i used this to create the object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177012/how-to-convert-string-to-date-object

Comment: That should work. If not, you could try `DateFormat.parse(String)`. It returns a `java.text.DateFormat` object. Just note that, the docs say parsing for it is lenient. Which means that, depending on your string you may or may not get the desired result.

Comment: After testing it i do get what i want "06/13/2013"

Comment: Awesome. However, I might still try to use `android.text.format.DateFormat` so that you don't have to worry about time zones and locale.

Comment: I know its taboo to ask but can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075824/android-fragment-with-viewbinder

Comment: Haha It's not taboo. I enjoy being able to help other people out. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: It should be fine since the date thats being put into the database is from their device right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31731/discussion-between-don-and-jcaruso)